# Flask with firebase_admin async firestore client runtime error: Event loop is closed

Tags: flask, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio, firebase-admin

When running a Flask application in combination with an async firestore client, a runtime error 'Event loop is closed' appears the second time loading the page.

Example app:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore_async
from flask import Flask

cred = credentials.Certificate('credentials.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore_async.client()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def hello_world():
    await db.collection("product").get()
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried to run this application, which works correctly until the second load of the page.
When running the app with a wsgi worker, the error sometimes appears and sometimes does not.
I also tried creating a new client for every request, but the issue remains.

Comment: Flask is a synchronous web framework. You should not be using async routes with it.

Comment: They do have support for async when installing with `pip install flask[async]` (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/async-await/)